# Missing async methods in MongoDB.Driver 2.22.0

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core

I'm working on integrating MongoDB / LINQ with my codebase, and I keep reading about these `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `ToListAsync()` methods from the MongoDb Driver.  However, I don't have those available.  Am I missing some NuGet package that everyone else uses?  I'm on .net 7.0.

```
using Mangler.Common.Functions;
using ManglerAPI.Infrastructure.Mongo;
using ManglerAPI.Stories.Entities;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace ManglerAPI.Stories.Repositories;

public interface IStoryRepository
{
    Task<OperationResult<Story>> GetById(long id);
}


public class StoryMongoRepository : IStoryRepository
{
    private readonly IQueryable<Story> _stories;

    public StoryMongoRepository(MongoClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _stories = clientFactory.GetClient<Story>("Stories");
    }
 
    public async Task<OperationResult<Story>> GetById(long id)
    {
        // FirstOrDefault does not exist.
        var data = await _stories.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            
        return data is null ? 
            OperationResult<Story>.Failure(ResultCode.EntityNotFound) : 
            OperationResult<Story>.Success(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported the library with `using MongoDB.Driver;`? And show us your code that attempts to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `ToListAsync`?

Comment: edited the post to add code, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the `IQueryable<T>` is from the *System.Linq* which doesn't have the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and `ToListAsync` extension method.

Instead, you should use the `IMongoQueryable<T>` from *MongoDB.Driver.Linq*.

```cs
private readonly IMongoQueryable<Story> _stories;
```

And you need to modify

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

public class MongoClientFactory
{
    public IMongoQueryable<T> GetClient<T>(string collectionName)
    {
        MongoClient client = /* Mongo Client instance */
        IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase(/* Your database */);

        return db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName).AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like what i had, unless I'm missing something:

the `AsQueryable()` returns the IQueryable, not IMongoQueryable :(

EDIT: Im dumb, you're right.  The method signature is defined with IQueryable which is a base interface of IMongoQueryable haha.   My bad!

Answer (score 1):

These async methods are extensions for `IMongoQueryable`, not `IQueryable` (which is a base interface for `IMongoQueryable`). So you should work with the interface that is provided for you by `AsQueryable` method, ie with `IMongoQueryable`